# Linux server not connecting to Windows share suddenly

Tags: samba, linux

I have a Ubuntu box running in a windows LAN. The Ubuntu box has the following line in /etc/fstab:

```
//192.168.47.130/Data    /hqserver    cifs            credentials=/etc/cifspw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777     0       0
```

This has been working just fine for weeks. My purpose for mounting this is to make backups of the windows folder.

However, for some reason this mount was disconnected, or dropped, or something. I no longer have access to the windows share at the linux location /hqserver . I ran the `mount -a` command and there was no output -- no errors, nothing. I pinged the Windows server at `192.168.47.130` and it is reachable. I did an `ls -alF` on root and this is the output for the `/hqserver` location

```
d?????????   ? ?      ?        ?                ? hqserver/
```

Then `cd` into `/hqserver` and do an `ls -alF` gives me:

```
ls: cannot access .: Cannot allocate memory
total 4
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?                ? ./
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 2011-12-19 07:01 ../
```

Any idea what is going on!?

Comment: Have you tried unmounting/remounting e.g. with smbmount?

Comment: Have you tried another share on that server or created a new share on another server to see if you are getting the same issue?   Also have a look at this as you are not the only one having this issue - http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/kernel-3-1-1-cifs-issue-ls-cannot-access-cifs-mnt-cannot-allocate-memory-help-205424951.html

Comment: I have tried to unmount and remount. I tried creating a new mount point in `/etc/fstab` mounting to a new directory (`hqserver_2`). When I executed `sudo mount -a` I received the same issue. @enterzero -- It doesn't look like that link works, but I found two other locations that have (I believe) the same information. http://jlcoady.net/windows/how-to-resolve-mount-error12-cannot-allocate-memory-windows-share is one, and a discussion is found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=869994 I can't get onto the Win machine yet, but will try later tonight and post back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

I followed the instructions on [this](http://jlcoady.net/windows/how-to-resolve-mount-error12-cannot-allocate-memory-windows-share) site (thanks to enterzero). As point out in the discussion linked in the page, the Windows machine needs to be told to act like a file server. I'm glad it worked. If the link goes down, here are the instructions:

1. Set “HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\LargeSystemCache” to “1″.
2. Set “HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size” to “3″.
3. Restart the “server” service.

Viola!